# Custom function unable to detect i the value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am creating a function which will allow me to return the row number. The user will give a matrix form range and a value. The function should bring back the row number. But the problem is that ith iteration thing is not working.

for example

```
FINDROW(some range from excel selection, 4) = 4
FINDROW(some range from excel selection, 7) = 7
```

It just returns back the value that I give. Any idea why?

```
Function FINDROW(MAT As range, value)
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
For Each valu In MAT
        If valu = value Then
            If (i Mod 10) = 0 Then
                FINDROW = 10
                Exit Function
            Else
                FINDROW = i Mod 10
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
i = i + 1
Next valu

FINDROW = "Not Found"
End Function
```

If i give FINDROW = "hello" then it brings back "hello". So one thing is for sure that FINDROW is working. I just want it to return the mod of i or rather row number

Comment: Works fine here (in as much as the code does as written). It's not going to return a row number necessarily though.

Comment: How are you returning "Hello", there is no way for that function as written to pass `Value` to `FINDROW`